# Can I tell EntLib to ignore a property in my business object when call ExecuteSprocAccessor?

Tags: .net, object, enterprise-library

Let's say I have a business object with 5 properties and a sproc that returns 4 columns with names matching 4 of those properties. The call to ExecuteSprocAccessor will fail. Is there a way I can mark the 5th property with an attribute, for example, to tell EntLib to ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this when you create the mapper. Basically, something like this:

```
var results = db.ExecuteSprocAccessor("some_sproc",
    MapBuilder<MyTargetType>.MapAllProperties()
        .DoNotMap("SomethingThatDoesntMatch")
        .Build(),
    param1, param2, param3);
```

That'll match all the parameters to results by name, but not map anything to the property SomethingThatDoesntMatch.

Something to be aware of: creating the result set mapper by the MapBuilder is kind of expensive, and it doesn't get cached automatically. If you're doing this call in a loop, it'll probably be slow. I'd recommend creating the mapper ahead of time and holding onto it, or creating the accessor separately and holding onto the accessor.

Comment: Right now I'm not even using a mapper. I just build my objects carefully so they match up with the columns my sprocs are returning. It's extremely clean and works in most instances. I was hoping I could simply decorate the properties I don't want mapped with an attribute. Oh, well. Right now, I'm running through a loop in my logic layer and copying over the objects—parameter by parameter—that I get back from the sproc accessor into a list of objects that contain the few other paramters that I need. If I have performance issues, I'll test both methods and use the faster one. Thanks!!!

Comment: Well, you are using a mapper, it's just implicitly being created for you. Yeah, in this case you'll have to explicitly create one. We very deliberately kept things simple; we just wanted to make it easier to consume database results, not accidentally build an ORM tool.

Comment: Ah. You're on the EntLib team. Cool. Yeah, getting a list of objects back from my sprocs is super slick. I really like it. Thanks for your help.